# ReactiveCococa: Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, reactive-cocoa

I am using carthage v0.18 on mac 10.12 (Sierra).

Cartfile:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa
```

I got error:

Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0:

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

### solution

When specifying a dependency **without** [version requirement in a Cartfile](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile), Carthage would checkout the latest release (taken by a git tag).

To find out the latest release of ReactiveCocoa repo, go to [releases page](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases). As of writing this (September, 16, 2016), the latest release is v4.2.2.

The 4.2.2 supports Swift 2.3.

However, the work to support Swift 3 is in progress and is being constantly committed to **master**. Thus, your change to Cartfile works.

### recommendation

During this stage (while there is no release with Swift 3 support) I would suggest you to lock your work toward the particular commit (see the format below). In this way, you would not accidentally, update the dependancy, while adding others, for example.

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "some-commit" # some commit hash
```

When you are ready to check out the new changes from ReactiveCocoa repo, you could replace the version requirement with "master" and hit `carthage update`.

This is how I worked on [Giraffe](https://github.com/evgeniyd/Giraffe) during Xcode 8 & Swift 3 betas time.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding 'master' on the end in cartfile:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "master"
```